# Ionian modes in Musixtex (fill in the missing notes)

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to display a rectangle to fill in the missing notes, the starting code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras



\begin{document}
Fill in the missing notes in the following Ionian modes:\\

G Ionian\\

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    \sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setclef1\bass
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startpiece%
    \notes\wh{G*IJ*L*N}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output should be:
[image: expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

- draw a `\framebox`
- shift it to the left
- shift it down.

Macro `\fbx` lets you change required parameters in just one place: adjust the 3 paramters there. I switched from `\notes` to `\NOtes` to provide some more space for the boxes. Also did some rewriting of your `\notes` line.

Using `pt`'s as length was straight forward. For more flexibility you may want to use quantities musixtex defined itself, i.e. multiples of some base data.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
    % removing, what's not needed here
    %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{polyglossia}
    %\setmainlanguage{spanish}
%   \usepackage{tikz}
%   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
%   \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\usepackage{musixtex} 
%\input{musixlyr}
    %\input {musixcho}
    %\input {musixdat}%fecha
    %\input {musixfll}
    %\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
    %\input {musixper}%percusión
    %\input {musixppff}
    %\input {musixstr}
    %\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
    %\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
    %\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
    %\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

% ~~~ adjust -4pt, 20pt and 30pt as needed ~~~
\newcommand\fbx[0]{\raisebox{-4pt}{%shifting everything down
                        \loffset{1}{%shifting content to the left
                            \framebox(20pt,30pt){}}}}% the desired empty field

\begin{document}
Fill in the missing notes in the following Ionian modes:\\

G Ionian\\

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    \sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setclef1\bass
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startpiece%
%    \notes\wh{G*IJ*L*N}\en
    \NOtes\wh{G}\fbx% making a bit more room  
    \wh{IJ}\fbx\wh{L}\fbx\wh{N}%\en 
    \en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```